# Stanford Engineering Everywhere CS106B C++ Libraries in XCode 4.6.2

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

Like many others, I'm taking the CS106B class on iTunes and, although the class is old, I am attempting to use the Stanford C++ libraries that are current.  They are found here:  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/.

During the Build Phase of projects, I have inserted into "Link Binary with Libraries" the files "random.h" and "libStanfordCPPlib.a".  When I do this, I get the following error messages:

```
Check dependencies

warning: skipping file '/Users/lewis/Documents/Think Like a Programmer/CS106/VotingSimulation/../../../Programming Abstractions/Assignment 1/Assignment1-xcode/0 - Warmup/StanfordCPPLib/random.h' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.h' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/lewis/Documents/Programming Abstractions/Assignment 1/Assignment1-xcode/0 - Warmup/StanfordCPPLib/libStanfordCPPLib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/lewis/Documents/Programming Abstractions/Assignment 1/Assignment1-xcode/0 - Warmup/StanfordCPPLib/libStanfordCPPLib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "randomChance(double)", referenced from:
   _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5 and XCode 4.6.2.  I have set the Build Settings Base SDK to OS X 10.7 for both the Project and the Target.

It appears to me that the "libStanfordCPPlib.a" file may be an archive file that I have to unarchive before I can link the implementation code for the header files.  Is this what I need to do, and if so, how do I do it?  Am I doing something else wrong in linking the files?

I'm a noob and I'd appreciate help from anyone who has been successful in getting the current Stanford CS106B C++ libraries to work in XCode 4.6.2.

Comment: Did you look into the skipped file of the wrong type? `sourcecode.c.h`??

Comment: Curiously, there's no such file named "sourcecode.c.h" on my computer.  Is this a file that XCode builds during the Frameworks & Libraries build phase?

Comment: I'm so new to XCode that I may be missing something that is obvious to everyone else.  Can you or anyone else give me some simple steps for the correct way to link to the libStanfordCPPlib.a file and the header files?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself after upgrading to the newest version of xcode (ver. 5.0, OSX ver. 10.8.5).

Try switching the architecture of the project to 32-bit Intel (i386).  The default is "Standard Architectures 64-bit Intel (x86_64)".

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using xcode 6.4 and trying to work through the cs 106b course work, I had the same issue of not being able to run the sample files and assignment files (can be found here btw http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1136/ ). After changing the Architectures for both the Project and Target to 32-bit-intel as listed above I still received errors. I had to take the additional step of changing the OSX deployment target from 10.10 to 10.8 under the Project info.

This allowed the program to build but I received a notification that i needed to install the Java Runtime Environment, and there was no consult output. Installing this did not resolve the issue. I was only able to fully execute the code after installing the Java Development Kit. I am now able to compile all files for the course.

I hope this update helps more recent attempts to access this info.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've found an answer to your problem by now, but as I was suffering from a similar problem, trying to get xcode 5.1 to compile Warmup.cpp, I thought I'd post my solution for those others trying to get xcode to work with the cs106b libraries.

After struggling with xcode 5.1.1 and 5.0.2, I downloaded xcode 4.6.3 off of the apple dev site, www.developer.apple.com, and trashed the later versions.  After installing 4.6.3, I still got errors, but after switching the Architecures for the Project and for the Target, to "32-bit-Intel", as messysaurus suggests, the warmupp.cpp compiled fine.  Trying this same technique with xcode 5.1.1 and 5.0.2 yielded no results.

Hope this helps anyone else running into problems.